# Scrolling the page using SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter

I try to use SingleChildScrollView to create the scrolling page but it comes out the error, how could I solve the problem? The result is that the fixed appbar and a scrollable form.
The error: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`
The error seems to tell me that the height is not enough but I am frustrated in what mistakes I have made.
the code I designed:

```
import 'package:dailyreport/weatheritem.dart';
import 'package:scroll_snap_list/scroll_snap_list.dart';

class ReferenceDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReferenceDetailState createState() => _ReferenceDetailState();
}

class _ReferenceDetailState extends State<ReferenceDetail> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late Function slideAction;
  List<Widget> weatherData = [];
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  bool closeTopContainer = false;
  double topContainer = 0;
  int _focusedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemFocus(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _focusedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void getPostData() {
    List<dynamic> returnweather = WEATHERITEM; //get the weather data
    List<Widget> weatherlist = [];
    returnweather.forEach((post) {
      weatherlist.add(
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 120,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 40.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100), blurRadius: 5.0),
              ]),
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  post["weather"],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Text(
                  post["weather_name"],
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
    setState(() {
      weatherData = weatherlist;
    });
    SizedBox(height: 50.0);
  }

  int selectedRadio = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedRadio = 0;
    _onItemFocus(_focusedIndex);
    getPostData();
    controller.addListener(() {
      double value = controller.offset / 119;
      setState(() {
        topContainer = value;
        closeTopContainer = controller.offset > 100;
      });
    });
  }

  setSelectedRadio(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [Colors.orange.shade200, Colors.white])),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                color: Colors.black, size: 30),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          title: Text(
            '日報表',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 20.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    '項目名稱:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Chuk Yuen Shopping Ctr.30 project',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                title: Text(
                  '參考編號:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  '202012170000',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setSelectedRadio(1);
                },
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                title: Text(
                  '客戶編號:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setSelectedRadio(2);
                },
              ),
              selectedRadio == 2
                  ? Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 5.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: true,
                          hintText: '輸入客戶編號',
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : SizedBox(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  '發布日期:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        final initialDate = DateTime.now();
                        await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: initialDate,
                          //showEXTalkDay == false ? initialDate : exTalkDay,
                          firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 2),
                          lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 3),
                          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                            return Theme(
                              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
                                primaryColor: Colors.orange,
                                textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.grey)),
                              ),
                              child: child!,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                            child: Text(
                              '28/08/21',
                              /*showEXTalkDay == false
                            ? 'DD/MM/YY'
                            : '${exTalkDay.day}/${exTalkDay.month}/${exTalkDay.year}'*/
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                            child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/arrowupanddown.png')),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  '天氣:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: ScrollSnapList(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    onItemFocus: _onItemFocus,
                    itemSize: 150,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: weatherData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      double scale = 1.0;
                      if (topContainer > 0.5) {
                        scale = index + 0.5 - topContainer;
                        if (scale < 0) {
                          scale = 0;
                        } else if (scale > 1) {
                          scale = 1;
                        }
                      }
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: Opacity(
                          opacity: scale,
                          child: Transform(
                            transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale, scale),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Align(
                                heightFactor: 1.0,
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                child: weatherData[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Row(children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '工地現場工作',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: SizedBox()), //space between two elements
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 100,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Colors.orange.shade600),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }, //onpressed
                        child: Text(
                          '添加',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  '任務',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to give the height and width to the main return container, above the scaffold

Comment: Try to put your SingleChildScrollView in a Container and set width/height: `Container(width: double.infinity, height: double.infinity, child: SingleChildScrollView(...)`

Answer (score 0):

How about wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded`?

That mentioned at [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

> The Column has no Expanded children, so rather than take on the infinite height from its BoxConstraints.maxHeight, (the viewport provides no maximum height constraint), it automatically tries to shrink to fit its children. It cannot be smaller than its BoxConstraints.minHeight, though, and It therefore becomes the bigger of the minimum height provided by the ConstrainedBox and the sum of the heights of the children.

Comment: I wrap it and still failed, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Would you mind helping me spread to others? Thank you

Comment: Why not. If you can provide working example I'll try. But mind I'm noob too :)

Comment: In my opinion problem is related on `ScrollSnapList` and his parent `Expanded`

Comment: what about remove `Expaned` near `ScrollSnapList`? Why did you use flex at there?

Answer (score 0):

you should use SafeArea widget or Container widget as child of SingleChildScrollView